# Get the count of UNLOADed records inside Amazon Redshift stored procedure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, plpgsql

My UNLOAD statement is inside the stored procedure in Amazon Redshift. I would like to log information about the number of records unloaded to S3.

I used

```
GET DIAGNOSTICS integer_var := ROW_COUNT;

RAISE NOTICE 'Unload executed with %', integer_var;
```

But it logged into SVL_STORED_PROC_MESSAGES "Unload executed with 0", when actually more than 60K records were unloaded. So, I would like to get, "Unload executed with 60000".

Could anybody help, please

Comment: What makes you think `ROW_COUNT` would contain a count of rows unloaded? The only thing I could find was reference to a `MANIFEST` file that can be generated by `UNLOAD`, which will contain details of each file created and their row count.

Comment: I use ROW_COUNT after INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE to log the number of rows inserted, updated, deleted. The same solution I need for UNLOAD. Just to log the number of rows without creating additional logic to get this value